# Why is a router dropping connection?

Tags: wireless-networking, router

Wifi signal sometimes drops connection (it goes from 15Mbps to 0 for a moment and then back to 15). I try to find the reason for that. Firstly I contact ISP and they said there's no interference in their network. So the internet connection must be ok. I have a modem, which is connected with the router and TV (IPTV). TV signal is OK, I can watch SD and HD so I suspect modem works fine. I have bought a new router Archer C7, dual band (2.4 and 5GHz), suspecting the problem is with the old one. I've also changed ethernet cables, wifi channels, tried with different devices (computers, phones, tablets), turning TV off (if it maybe takes too much bandwith) but nothing works. RSSI is -46dbm and noise -93dbm so this is ok as well. What do you suggest me? What could I still try to fix the problem? Is there any tool or software for detecting these kind of problems?

Comment: When troubleshooting a wifi connection, always rule out if wifi is the problem or not by using a network cable. If the network cable also has the problem, then you can contact your ISP and let them get a mechanic to you. They can't always measure problems.

Comment: Your 15Mbps indicates a fairly week signal.  Its quite possible that something is generating some noise and knocking it out - check if the problem happens when devices are closer to the router.